# Dragon help in Skyrim. Can't escape

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was on my way to a temple to do a quest and of course a dragon shows up. I can't fight it since i am not skilled with arrows and my magic is very weak. (I only use it to heal mostly) I use the Ancient Nord Battle Axe of Cold, but the soul has run out so it isn't very.. cold anymore. I do carry an Orcich bow and an Elven bow along with Orcich arrows and Steel arrows.

So I escape into the indoors and complete the quest. I go back outside, try to fast travel as fast as possible, but the dragon is already attacking me. I try to run but I am surrounded by rocks and a lake. I try to fight but I die repeatedly and hardly do any damage.

I am completely stuck. I even tried to lower the game difficulty and that hardly made the dragon easier to kill. Help would be greatly appreciated. I do not want to go back before the quest, but if I have to I will.

I play on my PC, so is there a command I can put in so I can escape or so it goes away?

Comment: Dragons will land at some point but my strategy for dragons is normally Blade in one hand a Restoration Spell in the other, keep attacking and when it breathes on me i cast the spell to negate as much of the damage as i can while still attacking. easier with Dragonrend as it'll bring them down and when the aura is gone i just shout at them again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try and kill it or run even if it takes a few attempts. If there is no way either of those will work simply enter the console (tilde key), click on the dragon and type **kill**, this will instantly kill the dragon you will be able to go on your merry way.

Comment: If you have problems select the dragon ( wich sometimes happens ), you could type tgm wich enables god mode

Answer (score 0):

What I did sometimes was to get into a big city (or fast travel if you can). The dragon will show up, but half of the city will go and attack him, generally making almost all the damage.

You can just sit peacefully (with an [Nord Mead](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Nord_Mead_%28Skyrim%29)) and see how a 10% of the whole Skyrim population (about 15 people) fights that annoying dragon.

Comment: I am in the middle of nowhere so that wouldn't work. Thank you though.

Comment: @Dorothy can't you quick travel? Sometimes when a dragon is following you, unless it is very close, the game lets you fast travel.

Comment: I couldn't because it was already above me once I left the dungeon. I couldn't go back either because it was on me, I had to use commands to kill it.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion would be to get to the best cover possible, hwt your best weweapons, and shoot him and then get back to cover, and when he lands do anything that does the most damage.(I am mostly an archer so this is my only solution.)

Answer (score -2):

Just go underneath the lake and swim run as fast you can and go away from the dragon if you get hurt heal and just keep running till you get to a town which then they will probably help you from there